# Synology NAS, has File Station application a database and where can I find it?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, synology, phppgadmin, php-pgsql

Has Synology NAS DS212j a database for "File Station" application and where can I find it?
I couldn't find it with phpMyAdmin nor phpPgAdmin.
Some files created in File Station, I could find on the database of Media server in phpPgAdmin.
But those contain media files only, such as music and video.
If there is no database available for the File Station application, how do I  connect a database to File Station application in phpMyAdmin or phpPgAdmin?

Comment: This is probably too specific to this particular hardware vendor to be easily answerable here. Have you tried getting in touch with Synology? They should have a support channel. I don't know what a "File Station" is  - is it a file browser web application? If so, maybe it just reads files/folders dynamically from the disk?

Comment: A "File Station" is the storage application for shared files. Usually one connect to shared files by network shares in Windows, SMB or NFS. Web based applications are Video Station or Mediaserver on Synology NAS. Video Station and Mediaserver both have a database attached. However, for File Station I cannot find such database.

Comment: Maybe it just reads files/folders dynamically from the disk?

Comment: I really don't know and have not found any usefull information about this kind a thing yet. However, in a database you may be able to find double files faster and therefore also saving diskspace. If "File Station" is a storage location, why not with a database?

Comment: If that is the case, then ask Synology why they did it that way? We can only guess.

Comment: Additional thought: why not explain, in your question, what you actually want to achieve? If you are looking for a file listing, and the "File Station" is accessible via a standard filing system like CIFS, then you can just use directory readers in a scripting language, e.g. `glob()` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I now know that File Station is a kind of File System on which databases are build upon. Although there is storage for media files, like music, video, etc. I didn't find any storage for all other files. So you can keep those files in the "download" database, where they're stored from the download station. However, what about the files uploaded from a location of your computer? In what database are those files then stored?

Answer (score 0):

I emailed Synology and asked about a database for File Station. They responded: There is not yet database support for File Station. But perhaps in the near future that may change. So we have to wait and see.